# Microsoft styled tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently I asked a question on stackoverflow about multiline tabs. Below is the link

[multi-line tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083177/multi-line-tabs)

I was just wondering if its possible to make them like windows styled tabs, that is if a tab in first line is selected, I want to push it to the second line. The problem I have is I am creating dynamic tabs. Is it possible using Javascript/jquery, to calculate the widths of each tab and determine at which point a second line of tabs would be started?

Thanks

Comment: If you're happy to use Javascript, then the solution I gave you in that previous question isn't really very good.

Comment: Perhaps something like [Ext JS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/#sample-5) would suit you better. See: [http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tabs/tabs-adv.html](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tabs/tabs-adv.html)

Comment: @thirtydot. The example was useful. This is a new requirement over that. I want to use Javascript to move the location of selected tab to the second line, if the selected tab is on the first line. I hope what I am asking here sounds sensible.

Comment: can you provide an example of this "windows styled tabs"?

Comment: @aSeptik. In Windows, MyComputer => Properties.

Comment: Thanks Guys. I tried a workaround and its working

Comment: Please don't use that God-awful UI pattern. It is confusing.

Comment: @user508518 - take a look at my demo and let me know. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** *added Tab Auto-Resize.*

Tested on `Chrome` / `FF`

> - **DEMO & SOURCE:** http://ask.altervista.org/demo/microsoft-styled-tabs/

```
    $(function() {
        setLines();
        $('#windows-properties li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
        var $li = $(this).parent(); 
            $(this.hash).show().siblings('.property-content').hide();
            var liTp =  parseInt($li.position().top);
            if (liTp < lastLiPos) {
                $('li.line-' + liTp).wrapAll('<div id="move-lis"></div>');
                $('#move-lis').insertAfter('#windows-properties li:last');
                $('li.line-' + liTp).unwrap();
                setLines();
            }
            $li.addClass('selected').siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
        });
        var $lstLi = $('#windows-properties li:last');
        var lastLiPos =  parseInt($lstLi.addClass('selected').position().top);
        $('.property-content:last').show();
    });
//.... other part of code in the demo source ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how windows does it, but i don't think this will be possible with dynamic tabs. Instead you can create two lists instead of one. Or better still you can use script to make two lists from one, so that both the lists span the entire line width & you don't have to hard code anything.