# Stacking jquery tabs on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Have you ever looked at the burn option in windows media player?
The tabs are stacked in a 2-layer format.

I was wondering if it were possible to get this with jquery or any other tool on the web

Comment: This can be done with CSS positioning. If you want a more useful answer, I would suggest posting the relevant parts of your tabs markup and JS code/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This questions is answered here: [Is there a Jquery tab control which handles multiple lines of tabs well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624516/is-there-a-jquery-tab-control-which-handles-multiple-lines-of-tabs-well)

Also, it's strongly discouraged to use multiple lines of tabs: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/tabs.html